# Select() send and receive with same socket descriptor

Tags: c, unix, select, client, recv

I am wanting to use select to receive and send on a client/server on the same socket descriptor (serverside).

```
timestruct* myTime;
sockfd = accept(listeningFd, 0, 0);

while(1)
    FD_ZERO(&my_fd_set)
    maxFd = sockfd
    FD_ZERO(&my_fd_set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &my_fd_set);
    select(maxFd+1, &my_fd_set, &my_fd_set, NULL, myTime);

    for (j=0; j<=maxFd; j++)

    if(FD_ISSET(j, &temp_fd_set))
        if(j==sockfd)
            send()
        if(j==sockfd)
            recv()
```

This is essentially what I want to do. Obviously this won't work because sockfd is going to be the same value for sending and receiving. Is there a way I can do this without using fork()??
Currently I have a blocking recv and send but the server could be required to recv multiple commands while another command is being processed to send back to the client. 
I am very knew to c and also 'select()'. Because select has the three fd_set options (read, write, execute) I thought maybe I could do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use different sets for the `rfds` and `wfds` parameters to `select`, so you can distinguish when `sockfd` is in one set but not the other.

```
fd_set rfds;
fd_set wfds;
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_ZERO(&wfds);

FD_SET(sockfd, &rfds);
FD_SET(sockfd, &wfds);
if(select(sockfd + 1, &rfds, &wfds, NULL, myTime) < 0) {
    perror("select");
    return -1;
}

if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rfds))
    recv();
if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &wfds))
    send();
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks, it works now! It seems so obvious now! I was trying everything but this. :/